# Load Balancer - recovery actions on failed instances

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I know that LB probes instances for health within some time period. Also i know that recently LB was updated with support for custom probes. For all I know and could find, only action LB does on receiving codes other than 200 (OK) is to stop forwarding traffic to it.
Is there any way for a load balancer to do some recovery action when notices that instance doesn't respond to probing? By recovery action I mean either restarting problematic instance or notifying some service that can take further action.

Answer (score 0):

Taking corrective actions is not part of LB job. LB job is just what its name suggest - balance traffic across instances. When we read a bit deeper [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj151530.aspx) we will see that

> If the Guest Agent fails to respond with HTTP 200 OK repeatedly, the
>   Azure Load Balancer marks the instance as unresponsive and stops
>   sending traffic to that instance

The point is that the faulting instance will be set to "unresponsive". And now it is the job of Windows Azure Fabric Controller to manage instances. It checks for their status, and if something wrong - takes corrective actions.

Comment: Does that mean that LB by marking the instance unresponsive will cause starting of an appropriate corrective actions in Fabric Controller?  Than we might say that LB by setting the instance status indirectly notifies FC that something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the custom load balancer probe is that it contains custom logic to decided if the instance is healthy/ready to receive requests from the load balancer. Like @astaykov already explains, it's not the job of the load balancer to take corrective actions, it's up to the Fabric Controller. But the Fabric Controller only monitors what it knows. Maybe you're spinning up an executable in a startup task and you want your instance to reboot whenever this process is offline (think of a Node process for example).

Your custom load balancer probe could return a status 500 if this process is offline and try to restart it. In the meanwhile the load balancer will not forward the requests to that specific instance. In your probe you can also try to restart the process, and if this fails after a few times, you can request a reboot yourself (in a clean way):

[RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.requestrecycle.aspx)